# How to troubleshoot long running JDBC issue?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, classloader, weblogic11g

We have an application that is experiencing intermittent slowness due to STUCK threads.  From dumped stack traces, we are piecing together that it always seems to be a running thread that appears to be taking too long (causing other threads to wait for the JDBC driver to clear) but that's where the trail ends.

Is there a way to figure out what this thread is doing or are there any possible causes/common issues that may be applicable here?

```
]", which is more than the configured time (StuckThreadMaxTime) of "600" seconds. Stack trace:
java.util.zip.ZipFile.getEntry(Native Method)
java.util.zip.ZipFile.getEntry(ZipFile.java:161)
java.util.jar.JarFile.getEntry(JarFile.java:209)
java.util.jar.JarFile.getJarEntry(JarFile.java:192)
sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader.getResource(URLClassPath.java:757)
sun.misc.URLClassPath.getResource(URLClassPath.java:169)
java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:194)
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:249)
java.sql.DriverManager.getCallerClass(DriverManager.java:477)
java.sql.DriverManager.getDrivers(DriverManager.java:373)
oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:543)
oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.getPhysicalConnection(OracleDataSource.java:404)
oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource.getPooledConnection(OracleXADataSource.java:674)
oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource.getXAConnection(OracleXADataSource.java:267)
oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource.getXAConnection(OracleXADataSource.java:134)
```

Our setup is WebLogic 10.3.6, multiple managed servers, multiple GridLink Data Sources.  This application in particular shares a managed server with another app, but they each have their own GridLink DS.

Comment: Tracing back through the stack trace - at the bottom you are getting a pooled connection, this then uses an Oracle driver causing something to be dynamically loaded (`java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass()`) - probably the driver - and the class is being loaded from a JAR file and JAR files are just zip files so it is extracting the desired class by iterating over the zipped JAR archive so it can be loaded. There does not seem to be anything particularly unusual about this sequence.

Comment: Right, I find myself always asking, what is it doing after it hits Native Method?  Would it point to blocking on a query (I didn't think it was, because this is for loading a class into memory), or blocking on I/O while it's reading the JAR? Is it normal for it to be reading the JAR? As in, I think this is happening each time a connection is fetched but I thought a class is only supposed to be loaded once, not multiple times?

Answer (score 0):

As per my experience, The DBA should be able to help you to track the threads and the running sql statements and how much time it took each statement to get executed.

Comment: Hi - I was wondering if "ZipFile.getEntry(Native Method)" is indicative of something wrong with query? This helps improve my understanding in troubleshooting this kind of issue. As for DBA, we do have a monitoring system in place, but sometimes it seems to be dwarfed by other DB jobs.  Is there something specific I can ask the DBA to look for? Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible to kill all the process that are running against the DB? Run your process and ask the DBA to run the sql tracing and monitor the session that is created by your process. Expert DBA can give you great details and suggestions like indexing, etc ...

Answer (score 0):

Can you run the application locally? You can attach Java VisualVM (It's part of the Oracle JDK. The command is `jvisualvm`) to the process and monitor it until you see the stuck thread. Visual VM is also great at finding memory leaks.

If you can't run it locally, perhaps you could SSH to the running instance with `ssh -Y` or `ssh -X` to forward X11 (assuming the server is running Linux). Then you can run VisualVM on the server but see the output locally (if you're not developing on Linux, you'll need to install an X11 server for Windows/Mac).

Comment: I can run the application locally, but I don't think I can reproduce the problem.  If I have access to use jvisualvm on the server, what should I look for in the tool?  Would there be more information in stack traces there or is there some other statistics/data point I should look at?  Trying to get a sense of what I should look for, thanks!

Comment: There's never one thing. It's going to be different with every use care. In your situation, I'd monitor the threads, look at their states and try to identify anything unusual. Watch your resource consumption over time as well.